# Irrelevant change of button size in Right to Left orientation

Tags: java, swing, orientation, jscrollpane, right-to-left

I have 9 jbuttons added to jpanel and the panel added to jscrollpane and it added to jframe.

http://www.pic1.iran-forum.ir/images/up9/95426323683658592564.jpg

when i change frame orientation by:
`applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);`

the panel move to right and size of buttons got fixed and wouldn`t fill the panel but you see in the image below that scrolbar is fill all width of panel

http://www.pic1.iran-forum.ir/images/up9/60975202722295688553.jpg

(i used gridbaglayout for adding buttons and borderlayout.center for add scrollpane).

is that a bug in java or ?

EDIT:
its the simplest view . Does it help?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame{
private JButton[] arrayButton = new JButton[9];
private JButton btnLeft = new JButton("<");
private JButton btnRight = new JButton(">");
private JScrollPane scpButtons = new JScrollPane();

public MyFrame() {
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayButton.length; i++) 
        arrayButton[i] = new JButton("btn");

    JPanel pnlButton = initPnlButton();
    scpButtons.setViewportView(pnlButton);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(scpButtons, BorderLayout.CENTER);

           // comment it and see the result 
    applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);      
    pack();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    setVisible(true);
}

private JPanel initPnlButton() {
    JPanel pnlButton = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10,
            1, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0);

    int ind = 0;
    int row = 3;
    int column = 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < column; j++) {
            gbc.gridx = j;
            gbc.gridy = i;
            pnlButton.add(arrayButton[ind++], gbc);
        }
    }
    gbc.weightx = 0;
    gbc.gridheight = 3;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    pnlButton.add(btnLeft, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 4;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    pnlButton.add(btnRight, gbc);
    pnlButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 700));
    return pnlButton;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MyFrame();
}
}
```

Comment: ...or you are doing something wrong?? Well, I would guess the later. As a suggestion, consider posting the relevant section of your code or even better an [SSCCE] (http://sscce.org/) version of your code

Comment: 1) People do not get notified of edits to a question.  2) @Sujay did not promise to fix the problem, just offered some good advice.  3) Nice SSCCE, +1.  :)

Comment: hmm ... interesting: it's fine if toggled with by an action at runtime, it's not fine if toggled in the contructor (irrespective when it's done, even invokeLater after setting visibility doesn't help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after playing with lots of properties and moving up and down the statements i found the answer.
if  you put

```
scpButtons.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
```

after

`applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);`

everything will be okay and no need to `setSize(getWidth() + 1, getHeight() + 1);`

so funny it got a whle day from me  :) does c# or other langs have bugs like this?

if you let `SwingUtilities` bloc to run , befor resizing the window everything are yet LtR.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
private JButton[] arrayButton = new JButton[9];
    private JButton btnLeft = new JButton("<");
    private JButton btnRight = new JButton(">");
    private JScrollPane scpButtons = new JScrollPane();

    public MyFrame() {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayButton.length; i++)
            arrayButton[i] = new JButton("btn");

        JMenu mnuSettings = new JMenu("MENU");
        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        menubar.add(mnuSettings);
        setJMenuBar(menubar);

        JPanel pnlButton = initPnlButton();
        scpButtons.setViewportView(pnlButton);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(scpButtons, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pack();
        // [1]
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        //setSize(getWidth() + 1, getHeight() + 1);
        // [2]
        setVisible(true);
        // SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        // public void run() {
        applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
//here
        scpButtons.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
        // }
        // });
    }

    private JPanel initPnlButton() {
        JPanel pnlButton = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10,
                1, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0);

        int ind = 0;
        int row = 3;
        int column = 4;
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < column; j++) {
                gbc.gridx = j;
                gbc.gridy = i;
                pnlButton.add(arrayButton[ind++], gbc);
            }
        }
        gbc.weightx = 0;
        gbc.gridheight = 3;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        pnlButton.add(btnRight, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 4;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        pnlButton.add(btnLeft, gbc);
        pnlButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 700));
        return pnlButton;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyFrame();
    }
```

}

Comment: oh i lost 2 reputation for unaccepting last answer :(
please someone vote my answer up. 
thanx before ;)

Comment: good that you found a hack that seems to be okay - though I doubt that fullfils the RToL requirement: having the scrollPane in LToR leads to incorrect horizontal scrolling (zero is still at the left instead at the right)

Comment: hmm.. you/r customer doesn't mind that the horizontal scrolling happens into the wrong direction?

Comment: @kleopatra oh it doent bother people so much here in my country- because we used to use english localed programs .Even though some programs like firefox and fdm and.. have released farsi(persian) distributions but most of people still use english one.
but as soon as i understand the solution , i will fix it.

by the way , my customer is my MOM  ;)

Answer (score 4):

**Edit 4**

(Hopefully the very last :-)

The ultimate culprit seems to be the main viewport of the scrollPane: it gets confused when sizing its view in RToL once it had been smaller than its preferred. Didn't track what exactly goes wrong, but looks like a viable (short of finding the bug in core and nudge snoracle into fixing it ;) solution is to make the view implement Scrollablable, specifically implement

- getPreferredScrollableViewportSize to return getPreferredSize
- implement getScrollableTracksViewportHeight/Width to return true if height/width is less than parent height/width and false otherwise

JXPanel (contained in [SwingX](http://swingx.java.net)) is-a Scrollable which does the first by default and can be configured for the latter by setting ScrollableSizeHints as appropriate:

```
private JPanel initPnlButton() {
    JXPanel pnlButton = new JXPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    pnlButton.setScrollableWidthHint(ScrollableSizeHint.PREFERRED_STRETCH);
    pnlButton.setScrollableHeightHint(ScrollableSizeHint.PREFERRED_STRETCH);
    ...
}
```

With that in place, no further hacky lines needed, simply apply the CO after adding all components:

```
applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
pack();
setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
setVisible(true);
```

**Edit 2**

The more we (both @Reza Gh and me) play with options the more I tend to seeing the behaviour as a bug. To sum up our latest findings

- the scrollPane seems to be a major culprit (Reza)
- the misbehaviour starts once the panel had been resized at/below its preferredSize (note the arteficial - at least I hope it's not part of Reza's production code - setPreferred when creating the panel)

**Edit**

Playing a bit more, it looks to me like a very weird behaviour on instantiation. A snippet to play with (at the end of the instantiation)

```
pack();
// [1]
setSize(getWidth() + 1, getHeight() + 1);
// [2]
setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
setVisible(true);
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
    }
});
```

and comment 1, 2 or both

- comment both: frame comes up in packed size, maximizing it doesn't fill the frame but child is docked at right edge
- comment 1: frame comes up in maximized size, child fills completed content, then resize to packed and maximize again: child doesn't fill
- comment 2: frame comes up with nearly (one pixel bigger) packed size, maximizing (and all other resizing) correctly fills the screen

The exact behaviour probably depending on native component orientation as well (mine is LToR). On the whole, I think this is a bug somewhere in core handling of component orientation (not surprisingly, it's not as stable as we would expect after all these years).

Looks like a hack around is to resize (slightly by 1 or so pixel, max alone doesn't work) after a pack and then invoke the applyCO.

**Original**

This does not solve the original problem (which is to apply the componentOrientation on instantiation of the frame), only demonstrates how to safely toggle CO at runtime

```
Action createCOToggle(final JFrame frame) {
    Action toggleComponentOrientation = new AbstractAction("toggle orientation") {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            ComponentOrientation current = frame.getComponentOrientation();
            if (current.isLeftToRight()) {
                frame.applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
            } else {
                frame.applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
            }
            frame.getRootPane().revalidate();
            frame.invalidate();
            frame.validate();
            frame.repaint();
        }

    };
    return toggleComponentOrientation;
}
```

configuring an action-aware component with it, will make the frame behave as expected, that is fill the complete area. The many re/in/validates look weird - but turned out to be necessary (in jdk6) as we experienced in [SwingX test coverage](http://swingx.java.net)

Now my expectation would have been, that invoking that same action at the end of frame's instantiation would make it behave as well, that is

```
.... // configure/fill frame
setVisible(true);
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        createCOToggle(MyFrame.this).actionPerformed(null);
    }
});
```

Unfortunate, it doesn't. Currently no clue as to why not, sorry.

Comment: Althogh understanding your answer is wery hard to me!(couse im a beginer) thank you . now im sure that there is no solution for me :( thanks

Comment: ok i got it but why toggle in runtime- i need whole of my program to be RtL from start to the End- no toggle needed

Comment: there's always a solution, don't despair :-) See my edit for a hack (might or might not work always, no guarantee)

Comment: even Without invoklater it works - (idont know the exact resoan of using that here)

Comment: some issues
1- if you put apply... in invokeLater , it does not work until you resize the window . Observe it by adding a menu to the Frame.
2-After delete swinguti... block > if [1]and[2] be uncommented everything is ok until doubleclick on window and resize it(i dont this action name) and then make it larger size by dragging border with mouse . in this situation child with packed and docked in right

Comment: although this answer should be complete and essential, i dont understand it completely so i prefer my answer , so other beginers can  do this trick.