# Why JScrollPane does not work when containing a JXPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, swingx

I made a really simple test case:

- I have a global containing panel with a `BorderLayout` (panel1)
- This global panel contains a `JScrollPane` (scroll1)
- This `JScrollPane` contains a panel with a `BoxLayout` set on `PAGE_AXIS` (panel2)

And then i have this little piece of code adding components (`JLabel`'s) to the *panel2*:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
    panel2.add(new JLabel(String.valueOf(i)));
}
panel2.revalidate();
```

It works. Now i'd like to use a custom panel i've made that extends the `JXPanel` from SwingX. So *panel2* looks like in my test case:

```
public class Panel2 extends JXPanel {
}
```

It does not work anymore. The scroll bar does not appear. Why? Is there anything special to do when using `JXPanel` within `JScrollPane`?

EDIT:

After using `setScrollableHeightHint(ScrollableSizeHint.NONE);` on `panel2`, `panel2` resize itself regarding the number of components in it, this is not the behavior i want, i want the scroll pane to keep his fixed size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the scrollableHeightHint/scrollableWidthHint property of the JXPanel: it's defaul is FIT, change to one of the modes which don't (fill the viewport)

Comment: Unaccepted since it leads me to another problem. Edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

The scrollBars do not show probably due to the fact that the `tracksScrollableHeight` or `tracksScrollableWidth` method inside `JXPanel` returns true by default.

Please refer to kleopatra's answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128743/irrelevant-change-of-button-size-in-right-to-left-orientation) question. 
The key thing to keep in mind to is to set the `ScrollableSizeHint` to appriopriate value for your panel, in this case it will probably be `ScrollableSizeHint.NONE`

Comment: Can i change this by overriding those methods and call the ones defined in JPanel?

Comment: You should rather take a look at `setScrollableWidthHint` and `setScrollableHeightHint` methods